# Is there a better way to write generic lazy DbContext query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection

What I got so far is:

```
public DbSet GetQueryableLazy<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class, IContextEntity
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

And I can call it in the controller action like this:

```
IQueryable<Person> people = (IQueryable<Person>)repository.GetQueriableLazy<Person>()
                                  .Include("Addresses");
```

Where repository is a result of dependency injection in the controller. But it seems like my code above defeats the whole purpose of Dependency Injection because I'm making action In the controller depend on DbContext (since GetQueryableLazy returns DbSet) and if later on I'm switching from Entity Framework to NHibernate I'll have to replace:

```
(IQueryable<Person>)repository.GetQueriableLazy<Person>()
                                  .Include("Addresses");
```

Everywhere!

What I'm trying to accomplish is if I can create generic method that attaches to "DbContext.include()" all of my "parameters" and returns query based on those attachment, so the result would look something like this:

```
 public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryableLazy<TEntity>(params IContextEntity[] contextEntities)
    where TEntity : class, IContextEntity
{
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    return context.Set<TEntity>().Include(contextEntities);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's the leaky abstraction story. Each `IQueryable` implementation has its own enhancements that trickle beyond the "abstraction" of the interface.

Each mature ORM has a notion of including navigation properties into the query result (*eager loading*) to prevent *lazy loading*, which will fire N + 1 queries. The differences already begin with the lingo. Entity Framework talks about "Include", NHibernate about "Fetch", other implementations about "Expand". This trivial difference aside, it is very hard to hide the real implementation differences from a consuming layer.

Let's illustrate this by an effort to parametrize eager loading behavior based on expressions.

Entity Framework (EF) has several `Include` methods, the two most interesting are:

1. [`DbQuery.Include(string path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.include.aspx)
2. [`QueryableExtensions.Include<T, TProperty> (Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220213.aspx)

So if you want to abstract that away you have two options:

1) `IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>(params string[] includes)`
2) `IQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExpressions)`

OK, let's proceed with 2). Now look at [NHibernate](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.nl/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html). With NHibernate's LINQ API you can write

```
// snippet 1
var customers = session.Query<Customer>()
    .FetchMany(c => c.Orders)
    .ThenFetchMany(o => o.OrderLines)
```

With EF this would be

```
// snippet 2
var customers = context.Set<Customer>()
    .Include(c => c.Orders.Select(o => o.OrderLines))
```

So with EF as DAL you could use method 2. With NHibernate... you can't. The expressions in snippet 1 have different types, so they can't be entered by the `params` argument.

So try a third method, a fluent API, so we can enter expressions of different types? Let's say

3) `IJoinableQueryable<T> GetQueryable<T>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> includeExpression)`

Which returns an `IJoinableQueryable<T, TProperty>` (couldn't think of a better name). This interface should implement `IQueryable<T>` *and* offer a method to add a next "Include" or "Fetch" based on `TProperty` *and* one to do the same for `<T>`. This would mean that in order to please NHibernate, you'd make things needlessly complex when EF is used. And even then, sooner or later you're bound to encounter implementation details that cause different behavior or exclude specific combinations of includes depending on DAL.

#### Conclusion

Don't try to abstract specific features of a DAL implementation in order to make a DAL pluggable. A pluggable DAL is an illusion (and we've only covered one aspect now). But if you don't expose `IQueryable` in your service layer you can hide most of the DAL features from the rest of the application. One consequence would be that you use *specifications* in stead of expressions to parametrize service methods.

More on this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/

Comment: Don't forget that [there is a way to do includes that work on all LINQ providers](http://damieng.com/blog/2010/05/21/include-for-linq-to-sql-and-maybe-other-providers), although IQueryable is still a leaky abstraction.

Comment: @Steven I didn't forget - I didn't even know this method. A quick test shows that it works well with Entity Framework, but with linq-to-sql I see N + 1 queries with collections included in collecctions. Still, it's pretty neat.

Comment: I used to use this with LINQ to SQL, but L2S is more limiting with collections of collections, but doing single includes (like `c.Orders`) should work in most cases. But it is wise to keep SQLProfiler open in the background :-)